# Cannot install SQL 2008 Workstation Components on Windows XP SP2

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server-2008

i am trying to install the workstation components of sql server 2008 on my windows xp sp2 machine and during the setup, the only options i have to install are the database engine and sdk. all of the other options including books, workstation components are missing.

Using the same installer disks i was able to install the whole works on a server.

I do not have any version of sql currently installed on the xp machine..

am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need XP SP3 to install the workstation components. I've installed it on my laptop and it seems to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the prerequisites?:

Microsoft .Net Framework 3.5 SP1.

Windows Installer 4.5.

Windows PowerShell 1.0.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, prerequisites are included in the installation media.